# Clustering News Articles

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, tensor

I am currently working on a python project in which I need to scrape news articles of different categories from different websites
Since the same news is posted on different websites, I need to cluster the same kind of news posted across multiple websites into one.
How can I implement this?
The thing I have in my mind is to get keywords for every article and then group news articles with similar keywords together into a cluster.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
# %matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\abc_news.csv",error_bad_lines=False,usecols =["headline_text"])
data.head()

data.shape

data[data['headline_text'].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values('headline_text').head(8)


data = data.drop_duplicates('headline_text')
data.shape


punc = ['.', ',', '"', "'", '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}',"%"]
stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(punc)
desc = data['headline_text'].values
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(desc)

word_features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print(len(word_features))
print(word_features[5000:5100])


stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z\']+')

def tokenize(text):
    return [stemmer.stem(word) for word in tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())]


vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, tokenizer = tokenize)
X2 = vectorizer2.fit_transform(desc)
word_features2 = vectorizer2.get_feature_names()
print(len(word_features2))
print(word_features2[:50]) 


vectorizer3 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, tokenizer = tokenize, max_features = 1000)
X3 = vectorizer3.fit_transform(desc)
words = vectorizer3.get_feature_names()


# KMEANS CLUSTERING
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1,5):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i,init='k-means++',max_iter=10,n_init=10,random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X3)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,5),wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.savefig('elbow.png')
plt.show()

 

print(words[250:300])


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, n_init = 20, n_jobs = 1) # n_init(number of iterations for clsutering) n_jobs(number of cpu cores to use)
kmeans.fit(X3)
# We look at 3 the clusters generated by k-means.
common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-26:-1]
for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
    print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))
    
    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 6, n_init = 20, n_jobs = 1)
kmeans.fit(X3)
# We look at 6 the clusters generated by k-means.
common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-26:-1]
for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
    print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))
    
    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 8, n_init = 20, n_jobs = 1)
kmeans.fit(X3)
# We look at 8 the clusters generated by k-means.
common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-26:-1]
for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
    print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))
    
    
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10, n_init = 20, n_jobs = 1)
kmeans.fit(X3)
# Finally, we look at 10 the clusters generated by k-means.
common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-26:-1]
for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
    print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))
```

Data Source:

https://www.kaggle.com/thebrownviking20/k-means-clustering-of-1-million-headlines